# Why does AS sometimes accept oversized displacement and sometimes not?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I know that displacement in MOD+R/M fields is maximally a signed 32-bit integer. However, I've seen some inconsistent behaviour when I pass a value that is too large for 32-bit signed (but small enough for unsigned 32-bit).

Case in point:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
mov [eax + eax + 0xdeadbeef], al
mov [r10d + r10d + 0xdeadbeef], al
mov [rax + rax + 0xdeadbeef], al
mov [r10 + r10 + 0xdeadbeef], al
```

When I assemble (and dissasamble), I get the following results:

```
0:  67 88 84 00 ef be ad    mov    BYTE PTR [eax+eax*1-0x21524111],al
7:  de
8:  67 43 88 84 12 ef be    mov    BYTE PTR [r10d+r10d*1-0x21524111],al
f:  ad de
11: 88 04 00                mov    BYTE PTR [rax+rax*1],al
14: 43 88 04 12             mov    BYTE PTR [r10+r10*1],al
```

As it can be seen, for 32-bit registers (`eax`, `r10d`) the 32-bit displacement is taken literally (and interpreted as a signed 32-bit integer) and for 64-bit registers (`rax`, `r10`), it is discarded.

While I consider both to be reasonable outputs for the input, I do not immediately see the reason for this inconsistent handling. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the intel syntax module. It results in an error message if you use at&t syntax:

```
mov %al, 0xdeadbeef(%rax, %rax)
```

Results in:

```
Error: 0xdeadbeef out range of signed 32bit displacement
```

Update: The bug seems to be because the `baseindex` flag is set after `i386_finalize_displacement` is called which only detects the error if it is set. A simple fix is to move the flag set earlier. I don't see any obvious problem with that, and at least fixes this issue:

```
--- tc-i386-intel.c.orig        2012-01-16 04:06:06.000000000 +0100
+++ tc-i386-intel.c     2014-06-14 16:13:31.238740524 +0200
@@ -835,6 +835,9 @@
       memcpy (expP, &exp, sizeof(exp));
       resolve_expression (expP);

+      if (intel_state.base || intel_state.index)
+       i.types[this_operand].bitfield.baseindex = 1;
+
       if (expP->X_op != O_constant
          || expP->X_add_number
          || (!intel_state.base
@@ -882,9 +885,6 @@
            return 0;
        }

-      if (intel_state.base || intel_state.index)
-       i.types[this_operand].bitfield.baseindex = 1;
-
       if (intel_state.seg)
        {
          for (;;)
```